# c# conversion from "byte" type to "generic" "K" type

Tags: c#, algorithm, generics, data-structures

I have created huffman tree in c# by reading a binary file as sole argument using ReadByte(). After i calcuate the frequency of each `symbol` by the count of repetition of each symbol in that binary file. And i stored the byte read in `processingValue` which is of type "`int`" intially (after i tried it to make it of type `"K"` i mean `generic` which afterwards creates problems). But every thing until goes fine.
Please see the code below:

```
  public class Node
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public int symbol; //After i will make it generic by putting "K" at the place of "int"
            public int freq;
            public int is_processed;
        }
        public Node front, rear;
```

This huffman is constructor both of these function definition (above and below) are inside huffman class.

```
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
                {
                    int processingValue = stream.ReadByte(); //The problem is here when i tried to do Func<byte,K>
                    {
                        Node pt, temp;
                        bool is_there = false;
                        pt = front;
                        while (pt != null) 
                        {
                            if (pt.symbol == processingValue) //The problem is here it can's compare "byte" to "K" type.
                            {
                                pt.freq++;
                                is_there = true;

                                break;
                            }
                            temp = pt;
                            pt = pt.next;
                        }
                        if (is_there == false) 
                        {
                            temp = new Node();
                            temp.symbol = processingValue;
                            temp.freq = 1;
                            temp.left = null;
                            temp.right = null;
                            temp.next = null;
                            temp.is_processed = 0;
                            if (front == null) 
                            {
                                front = temp;
                            } 
                            else 
                            {
                                temp.next = front;
                                front = temp;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                stream.Close();
                //////////////////////////////
            }
        }
```

The problem occurs when I try to make this "`symbol`" as `generic` of type "`K`".I change the Huffman class as follows to do so :

```
         public class Node
        {
            public Node next, left, right;
            public K symbol; // "int" is replaced by "K"
            public int freq;
            public int is_processed;
            }
        public Node front, rear;
```

Now the problem created is wheni read the byte using `ReadByte()`i save it inside "`int`" type variable called "`processingValue`" in my code. I now i replaced "`int`" to "K" to make it generic. But when i do so i have an error saying that **no possible conversation from Byte to "K"**.
Could someone please give me equivalent code so as to make "`int`" type `processingValue` to work for `generic` type `"K"` because `"symbol"` must also work for "short"/"ulong" etc on 32/64 bit architecture to read a binary file to create frequency by counting the repetition of symbols present in that binary file.
I also tried `Func<byte, K>` (`Func<byte, K> processingValue = stream.ReadByte();`)  but it gave error :

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `byte' to `System.Func<byte,K>'
```

EDIT : I have changed the code to for Func but there is no error on compilation but 
on doing execution "mono filename.exe binaryFile.bin" //I am calculating frequency of symbols in this binary file. (The number of time symbol repeats is it's frequency), I have unhandled exception : please see the error below:(It just prints "check1" but not "check2" in the constructor of my code given below the error)

```
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$ gmcs test.cshp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$ mono test.exe toto.bin check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1
check1

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says exactly what the problem is - the compiler has no idea how to convert a `byte` to a random `K` which implements `IComparable<K>`. You simply can't do it, because it could be more or less anything.

If you want a generic Huffman tree which is parameterised by the symbol type, then you need to either

1. Get the user to provide you with your symbols already read in and converted to the appropriate type
2. Get the user to provide a function which converts `byte` to their choice of `K` (i.e. a `Func<K, byte>`) which your reading code can then use

I'd actually recommend the former, in general, because it encourages separation of concerns. It's generally a bad idea to build I/O into a data structure class, because then you're stuck with that and you can't read from a different source at a later date. Option 2 would allow you to keep as close to your existing code as possible.

Comment: thanks , Any algorithm to make as reference by achieving the goal by your second point ? Thanks

Comment: No algorithm required, just pass the function in as a parameter and use it when you need to do the type conversion. Everything else can stay the same.

Comment: sorry, Which function i have to pass in parameter ?

Comment: The one which provides the conversion from `byte` to `K`.

Comment: If i understand you correctly the function Func<byte,K> do the conversion.(if you see this "Func<byte, K> processingValue = stream.ReadByte();"). Do i have to pass "Func<byte,K>" in paramter , Please explain a bit. It's like a puzzle for me.Thanks

Comment: you mean i have to create several function for several data types, suppose if the data type is short pass the "K" to function call of "short"type conversion. If it is ulong  then pass "K" to function definition of "ulong" type function call and in their respective function definition do the conversion. Is it you are saying ?

Comment: Okay, a `Func<byte, K>` is an object which represents some code, so you can call it and that code will run. This lets you pass not just data (information) to a function but also _behaviour_, which makes it possible to write far more powerful general-purpose code. So you write your constructor like `public Huffman(string filename, Func<byte, K> converter)` and within the constructor body you treat `converter` like it's any other function - `symbol = converter(processingValue)`.

Comment: Further: a variable of type `Func<byte, K>` holds code which, if you wrote it as a method, would have a declaration something like `K func(byte b)`, assuming that `K` was known already. A `Func<byte, int>` is akin to `int func(byte b)`. They're just ways of writing objects which can hold code, so that code can then be passed around. Unfortunately C# makes this a more exotic concept than it is in some other languages, particularly the business of having to know about the `Func<>` and `Action<>` generic types (`Action` is for code which doesn't return a value).

Comment: I have done what you have just said please see the edited part below in asked question It gives unhandled exception (if you see the end of output and just prints "check1" not "check2", This check1 and check2 is for debugging purpose to know the error prone place). Thanks

Comment: please go to just constructor and Class containing main function, it will be bit easy for you to recognize the problem (because other part may confuse you and other functions are working properly).

Comment: The exception tells you what the problem is. Read the entire message.

Comment: i have read it, the file is not a multitude of 8 bytes so at the end it gives error. Last time when i was having symbol as "int" data type so it was working fine but i don't know how to change the Object creation in order to make it work (I mean : "Huffman < long > ObjSym = new Huffman < long > (args, BitConverter.ToInt64);"). could you please help me in that ?I am still not able to solve it.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you. I'm trying to get you to figure out how to solve it yourself. So your file isn't a neat multiple of the right number of bytes. How do you deal with that? Is that an overall error? Do you ignore the last few bytes that can't make up a full Int64 and pretend they were never there? When reading, you'll need to check how much you read against how much you wanted to read and take appropriate action in case not enough bytes were available.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is a bit more complicated than just casting K to byte or the other way around.

Here's one approach.

Define an interface `ICanLoadFromStream`, inheriting from IComparable, then put that interface as a `where` clause for K. Then instead of `stream.ReadByte()` call in interface method `LoadFromStream(stream)`:

```
public interface ICanLoadFromStream: IComparable{
   void LoadFromStream(Stream stream);
}

public class Huffman<K> where K :  ICanLoadFromStream{
...
}
```

The obvious complication is that even for byte, int, etc you'd have to implement a wrapper class.

NOTE: Keep in mind that not all stream types implement Length or Position (network streams), restructure your code to do a Read.

Comment: put comments if you have questions

Answer (score 1):

Your `Func<>` approach is one way to do this, but the reason you're getting an error is because you are trying to assign the result of `ReadByte` to the `Func` rather than call the `Func` to do the conversion.

Assuming you've got a type `K` then you'll have a `Func` something like this:

```
Func<byte,K> converter = b=>new K(b);
```

Now you just read the byte and pass it in:

```
byte byteValue = stream.ReadByte();
K kValue = converter(byteValue);
```

You'll need to pass the converter into the `Huffman<K>` constructor and store it in a member variable:

```
public Huffman(Func<byte,K> converter)
{
  m_Converter = converter;
}
```

The reason for this is you cannot creates instances the generic type parameter using their parameterized constructor. You can only call their default constructor.

Comment: this converter(..) is  an inbuilt function in c# ? Could you please explain me "converter = b=>new K(b);" this assignment  ?please ?

Comment: The line `Func<byte,K> converter = b=>new K(b);` creates a lambda which takes a `byte` and returns a `K`. The body on the lambda just creates a new instance of `K` passing `b` (which is a byte) to the constructor.

Comment: so this kValue will now contain the resultant conversion ? Am i right ?

Comment: I am doing in these sequence in a while loop {YOU CAN HAVE A LOOK IN MY CODE}.  Am i going right :  Func<byte,K> converter = b=>new K(b);
                   byte byteValue = stream.ReadByte(); 
       K processingValue = converter(byteValue);

Comment: Yes. Just declare the `converter` variable outside the `while` loop as it won't need to change.

Comment: errors are : error CS0304: Cannot create an instance of the variable type `K' because it does not have the new() constraint
z.cs(28,54): error CS0417: `K': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type
z.cs(40,43): error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type `K' and `K'

Comment: and it corresponds to line " Func<byte,K> converter = b=>new K(b);"

Comment: Ah, ok. You'll need to pass the `Func` into your `Huffman<K>` class constructor as you can't have a generic constraint that specified a parameterized constructor. Sorry, forgot to mention that. I'll update the answer.

Comment: you can use my code for that. would be more easy to write :) Thanks

Comment: but the Huffman class already contains the name of the file read as sole argument as parameter (see public Huffman(string[] args){...} ), and if i pass one more parameter in Constructor then what i will pass on object creation of this Huffman class (Right now i am doing this way in main class: Huffman<K>  ObjSym = new Huffman<K>(args); //object creation )

Comment: Have you noticed ? That i am doing all this ReadByte() procedure inside the constructor ? I am confused because this converter is already inside the constructor

Comment: So you'll want to change your constructor to `public Huffman(string[] args, Func<byte,K> converter)`

Comment: I have a confusion that the function is already inside the constructor. Then what is the need to do public Huffman(string[] args, Func<byte,K> converter) ?

Comment: Because the constructor is the constructor for all possible `Huffman<K>`, so it doesn't know how to define `converter`. Someone outside - someone who decides what the value of `K` actually is - has to provide that behaviour. They're the only person who can.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have managed to solve the problem.
The solution was my condition `while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)` when last read of file is not a multiple of (or smaller then the size of data type chosen then it gives un handled exception).

I solved this problem by changing this while() loop to for loop like this :

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (T));    
long length = stream.BaseStream.Length;
for (long position = 0; position + size < length; position += size)
{
  //other stuffs   
}
```